# create latex output for ivprobit?

Tags: stata, latex

Suppose I want to create the latex output for the example in ivprobit. That is:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r11/laborsup.dta
ivprobit fem_work fem_educ kids (other_inc = male_educ), first
margins, dydx(_all) pred(pr)
```

I want to have one column with the first stage, and one with the marginal effects.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more clever way of doing this that does not involve re-estimating the first stage:

```
webuse laborsup
ivprobit fem_work fem_educ kids (other_inc = male_educ), first
margins, dydx(_all) predict(pr) post
estimates store ivp
reg other_inc male_educ fem_educ kids
estimates store first_stage
estout first_stage ivp, style(tex)
```